# How to fix W3C CSS validation error - "Value Error Unknown Dimension" when using rem?

Tags: css, validation

According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem `rem` is a valid unit for CSS3. Why do I get so many validation errors from http://www.css-validator.org/validator?

Comment: The validator you're using is a fake copy - it's not the actual W3C CSS validator which is located at http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Thanks! Now I get way less errors. But it seems that using calc is not supported along all CSS3 browsers so I guess I'll have to change my CSS anyway :D

Comment: Use a fallback value. `width:80px; width:5rem;` will use the value 80px if the browser doesn't know about rems.

Comment: `calc()` [IS supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) in all "major" browsers, only opera mini is lagging support and therefore you can use a fallback, if that is an important browser of your website visitors...

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean but I often use something like width: calc(100% - 1rem);